# Resizing view when loading from a .nib file

Tags: iphone

I have a [.nib file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) created in Interface Builder with 1 UIView item, but when I initialize it programmatically, the view doesn't cover up the entire screen, leaving a small portion of the view beneath it visible.

It looks like the Y coordinate is at some negative position instead of at 0. I don't have a Navigation bar configured for the view but if I were to set it, the bar doesn't get shown.

I'm creating the view like this inside the appDelegate class:

```
MyCustomController *controller = [[MyCustomController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustomView" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:[controller view]];
```

Settings in Interface Builder for the view:

```
Orientation: Portrait
Status Bar: Gray
Top Bar: unspecified
Bottom Bar: unspecified
View mode: "Scale To Fill" 

View Size/Position: Set to "Layout" and the X/Y, Width/Height are readonly with 0,0,320,460
```

I've printed out the view's frame and [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] on 'viewWillAppear':

```
view.frame on viewWillAppear - x: 0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0
bounds - x: 0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0
```

I'm not sure why the view is getting shifted - what's the best place to read just the frame size once the view is loaded by the 'initWithNibName' method? That seems to be the workaround I can think of.

Comment: The status bar is being shown and not trying to keep it hidden. The view underneath my topmost is a UITabBarController and I can see about 90% of the tab bar buttons itself poking through.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my controller with a UINavigationController and the problem went away.